# Mapping a column of type list/set/map using datastax object mapper

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am trying to use datastax mapper, and it is working fine, for all the primitive types.

I am having trouble using it for Map type column in cassandra table.
Possibly, the issue is also with Set and List type of column.

Can Anyone help me on how to do this?

Just to make things clear, i am using below maven dependency

```
        <cassandra.version>2.1.7.1</cassandra.version>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cassandra.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>${cassandra.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

and using com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper

Below is the table column structure in cassandra,

```
features map<text, text>
```

Here is the how i have defined the vo that maps to table using datastax mapper,

```
@Table(keyspace = "keyspace", name = "mytable")
public class myVO{
    @Column(name = "features")
    private Map features;
   //getters and setters here
}
```

Here is how i am mapping using mapper

```
protected myDAO(Class<T> typeParameterClass) {
        this.mapper = new MappingManager(session).mapper(typeParameterClass);
    }

myDAO(myVO.class);
```

And, it throws below exception,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot map unknown class java.util.Map for field features
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.TypeMappings.getSimpleType(TypeMappings.java:67)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.ReflectionMapper.extractSimpleType(ReflectionMapper.java:196)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.ReflectionMapper$LiteralMapper.<init>(ReflectionMapper.java:63)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.ReflectionMapper$LiteralMapper.<init>(ReflectionMapper.java:57)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.ReflectionMapper$ReflectionFactory.createColumnMapper(ReflectionMapper.java:231)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.AnnotationParser.convert(AnnotationParser.java:166)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.AnnotationParser.parseEntity(AnnotationParser.java:109)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.MappingManager.getMapper(MappingManager.java:148)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.MappingManager.mapper(MappingManager.java:105)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty stupid mistake.
But the error message can be elaborate.

Anyone looking, mistake was, i was not casting the map in java to <String, String >.